Is it possible in BigQuery to alias a splat?
I have a BigQuery RECORD user_details, which holds their details like address, email, etc. I have several records like this, each has several fields underneath them, and they will change over time.
So in a typical BigQuery SQL query, I'll ask something like:
SELECT
user_details.*
FROM `my_table`

This is nice because it unravels the user_details RECORD to the top level, so that there will now be a column called email instead of a hierarchical column called user_details.record. My downstream users / customers are not SQL gurus, so best to keep it simple for them.
But now I have to worry about name clashes. What if I have a RECORD called spouse_details which also has an email, address, etc?
Now if I do a query like
SELECT
user_details.*,
spouse_details.*
FROM `my_table`

I have a column called email and another called email_1. Not only is this ugly, but I obviously don't know which one aligns to which.
I would like to do something like
SELECT
user_details.* AS user_,
spouse_details.* AS spouse_
FROM `my_table`

such that I get columns labelled user_email and spouse_email.
This is not possible, at least not the way that I wrote it.

Is there any way to do this?
I don't want to write the specific fields of the record. Ie, I don't want to write SELECT user_details.email as user_email, user_details.address as user_address... because:

It greatly expands the amount of code, making it less readable, and
The fields may change over time, and the splat will keep them all.




Consider below approach
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, 'user' AS type, user_details.*  FROM your_table UNION ALL
  SELECT id, 'spouse', spouse_details.* FROM your_table
) 
PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(email) email, ANY_VALUE(address) address FOR type IN ('user', 'spouse'))    

it assumes presence of some sort of id as in below data sample
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, STRUCT<email STRING, address STRING>('email11', 'address11') AS user_details, STRUCT<email STRING, address STRING>('mail12', 'address12') AS spouse_details UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ('email21', 'address21'), ('mail22', 'address22') UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, ('email31', 'address31'), ('mail32', 'address32') UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, ('email41', 'address41'), ('mail42', 'address42') 
)

and output will be


I think (personal opinion), that it is better for the readability purposes if you explicitly call out field names from the RECORD type and have them available in the columns. I think, the benefit of it (being readable, easy to debug) far surpasses the downside of it being an ugly looking query.
select 
  user_details.name as person_name, 
  user_details.email as person_email, 
  spouse_details.name as spouse_address, 
  spouse_details.email as spouse_email,
  ..
  ..
from table


Agreed, regarding readability.  However, I find a SQL query to be much more readable if it is, say, 50 lines of code instead of 200, especially since the splat is well known and easy to understand.
